# What is correct python syntax for this kind of list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

task: {x*y such that x belongs to S & y is iteration count }
where S is some other set
something like this:

```
j=0
[i*j for j++ and i in S]
```

`[s1*1, s2*2, s3*3...]`

Comment: You'll have to explain what you want more completely, as what you've described is a infinite sequence of 40*j, and we don't need to worry about the range at all.

Comment: when I first answered the question, `S` was `range(40, 100)`.

Comment: When looping through a sequence, the position index and corresponding value can be retrieved at the same time using the enumerate() function src: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

for your edited question, you want

```
[i * j for j, i in enumerate(S)]
```

---

python doesn't have `++` because it keeps a clear distinction between statements and expressions. use

```
[(i + 40) * i for i in xrange(60)]
```

another way to do this is

```
[i * j for i, j in enumerate(xrange(60), start=40)]
```

and yet another way is

```
[i * j for i, j in zip(xrange(40, 100), xrange(60))]
```

I think that the first is the best way to do it because it reduces function calls and is the most readable.

Also, if you don't know that you absolutely need a list, use a generator expression

```
((i + 40) * i for i in xrange(60))
```

This will allow you to process the results one at a time and never store a whole list in memory. You can pass a generator expression to stuff like `sum`, `max`, `min` and most other builtins.

Answer (score 1):

```
S = range(40,100)
[i*j for i,j in enumerate(S)]
```

Comment: There is a `start` parameter for `enumerate()` so you could use `enumerate(S, start=1)` instead.

Comment: @Aaron: Right. In his first example (since deleted), he had started at 1, throwing me off there. @KennyTM: Thanks, that's much better (if so desired).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) in conjunction with [`range`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range):

```
[x * (count + 1) for count, x in enumerate(range(40, 100))]
```

Look at other answers for (a lot of) other ways to do this :) :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it in a generator:

```
def fooGen(S):
    j = 1
    for i in S:
        yield i * j
        J += 1
```

Comment: OP has `j` start at 0 and a generator function is overkill for what a generator expression can trivially do.

Answer (score 0):

"""
task: {x*y such that x belongs to S & y is iteration count } where S is some other set
[snip unfortunate introduction of i and j]
[s1*1, s2*2, s3*3...]
"""

a very simple translation:

```
[x * y for y, x in enumerate(S, start=1)]
```

or

```
[x * (y + 1) for y, x in enumerate(S)]
```

Comment: but OP has the index starting at 0, not 1.

Comment: @Aaron: What are you calling "the index", y (the iteration count)? Look at his last line: [s1*1, s2*2, s3*3...] ... I see no zero.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the current element index as an incrementor

```
>>> S=[2,4,6,8]
>>> [i*(S.index(i)+1) for i in S]
[2, 8, 18, 32]
>>>
```

so your c-ish "j++" is S.index(i)+1

Comment: -1 this is so incredibly fugly. `index` traverses the list to find the index of `i` so you just took an O(n) operation and turned it into an O(n**2) operation! also, try `S=[2, 3, 3, 3, 4]`

Comment: the question was about using list comprehensions, nor "a fast way to" or "a beautiful way to"

Comment: 1) that's just a (lame) excuse for crappy code and 2) your crappy code doesn't even work.

Comment: there's your O(n): [S[i]*(i+1) for i in range(0,len(S))]